# Buttons that move a DIV left or right

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am attempting to make a div scroll left or right either with a mouseover effect or on-click. However, I am at a loss as to what is going wrong.

Here was my attempt to do this simply:

```
 <head>
    <style>
    #innerscroll{
    margin-right:0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="innerscroll"></div>
<img src="right.jpg" 
onmouseover="document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.marginRight = setInterval(('value' + 1), 100);" />
</body>
```

Now, trying this, I'm wondering why it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried a more complex approach that also failed. Here's the code for that:

```
    $('.nav-next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#innerscroll').animate({
            'margin-right' : '100px'    
        });                 
    });
    $('.nav-previous').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#innerscroll').animate({
            'margin-right' : '-100px'
        });                 
    });
```

My last question was closed because I guess I was not specific enough. Whatever details you need please ask for and I'll edit the question!

Edit: I have the option of using jQuery but I would rather not.

Edit2: I am using setInterval to time the mouseover effect. I am thinking that it will move via mouseover or it will move via a click event.

Comment: One problem is that the JavaScript names of CSS properties use intercaps instead of hyphens, so you need to write `.style.paddingRight` instead of `.style.padding-right`. Another problem is that `setInterval` doesn't return anything that you might plausibly want to use as a value for `paddingRight`.

Comment: Also, your two code-snippets differ in the important respect that the first one adds an action on mouse-over, whereas the second one adds an action on click. That's not a matter of "more complex" so much as of "completely different".

Comment: What value you want to set for image using document.getElementById('innerscroll').style.padding-right ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.style.paddingRight` instead of `.style.padding-right`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqzrY/14/)

Modified code:

```
<img src="right.jpg" 
onmouseover="onmouseoveronImge();" />
```

Since you are using jQuery you can attach mouseover event as below

```
<script>
  $('.nav-next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#innerscroll').animate({
        'margin-left' : '+=100px'    
    });                 
});
$('.nav-previous').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#innerscroll').animate({
        'margin-left' : '-=100px'
    });                 
});
 function onmouseoveronImge(){
       $('#innerscroll').animate({
          'margin-left': '+=100px'    
      });
}
</script>
```

Note: I don't think you want to use value return by setInterval. You should explain it in your question why you are using it.

Comment: really what he should be doing is not using document.getElementById and tagging his/her question 'jquery' -_-

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't return a valid value for `paddingRight`

Comment: @Shmiddty I know that. and I already asked a question about that in comment. I used it because he has this in his code.

Comment: @Shusl This shouldn't be an answer if it doesn't actually work as intended.

Comment: @Shmiddty it will work but I don't know OP intention behind use of setTimeout.

Comment: @Shusl I used the "setInterval" as a way of making the div move during the duration of the mouseover. I had a feeling that wouldn't work, but I don't know what will.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is using jquery too, like this:

using 2 buttons, one for left move and other for right move

```
$('#innerscroll').animate({
'marginLeft' : "+=50px"
});
```

and

```
$('#innerscroll').animate({
    'marginLeft' : "-=50px"
});
```

you can make a function and pass the value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Padding can't be negative value. Animate margin instead.
So your code should look like this:

```
 $('.nav-next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#innerscroll').animate({
        'margin-left' : '100px'    
    });                 
});
$('.nav-previous').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#innerscroll').animate({
        'margin-left' : '-100px'
    });                 
});​
```

Working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vqzrY/

Comment: I see that this works great, but how would I make it incremental? I tried this but it doesn't work:
[code]
     $('.nav-next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#innerscroll').animate({
            'margin-left' += '100px'    
        });                 
    });
    $('.nav-previous').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#innerscroll').animate({
            'margin-left' -= '100px'
        });                 
    });
[/code]

Comment: Your code has syntax error. Correct format: `'margin-left' : '-=100px'` Here's fiddle with incremental moving: http://jsfiddle.net/vqzrY/9/ But I suggest you using variable for offset inside animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have markup like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Setting the `padding` on either `#container` or `#content` will not make the inner `div` move.  You want to set the `margin` on the inner `div` to make it scroll horizontally, and set `overlay:hidden` on the outer `div`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That truth escaped my mind when I typed this up.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using the jQuery UI library? Your second example looks like you might.

Try this, does it do something similary to what you are trying to accomplish?

```
<div id="innerscroll">
  Some Content...
</div>

<div class="nav-next>
  Next
</div>

<div class="nav-previous">
  Previous
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.nav-next').click(function(e) {
      $('#innerscroll').animate({
          right: 100    
      });                 
  });

  $('.nav-previous').click(function(e) {
      $('#innerscroll').animate({
          left: 100
      });                 
  });
</script>
```

If not, your example looks like you are doing a couple things:

- Setting the padding with CSS
- Setting padding *on* mouseover

Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I tried this with no results. And yes, I am trying to set the padding to 0 initially, which I do with a style tag right above the script in the head. I tried disabling it thinking that will solve the problem but it didn't. I am starting to believe there is something wrong with my site, as all the scripts you guys gave me don't work once I implement it into my site: strandoc.com/gallery.php

Comment: Ok... now in seeing your site, this is what you want [Bootstrap Carousel](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel)... It uses Twitter Bootstrap, but the JavaScript is built on JQuery. It looks like you are trying to do exactly what the Carousel was built for.